# TypeError: files.push is not a function

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying the name of files on an input using state and rendering the titles to the page. The first file renders correctly to the page, however the second inputted files gives me an error that reads "TypeError: files.push is not a function". The push works correctly because I can see the array in the console. I have setFiles in order for the page to re-render and show the name of the files.

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])

const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    files.push(event.target.files[0].name)
    setFiles(event.target.files[0].name)
}
```

Comment: Please read the docs at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html. In particular the section entitled 'What does useState return?'

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't know what `.name` is, but it doesn't sound like an array that you want to set files to. Maybe `setFiles(files.concat(event.target.files[0].name))` is what you want? An [mcve] seems necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify the state directly as is a React anti-pattern, what you should do is use the `setFiles` function to update it, and instead of using push you can use the spread operator to create a new array with the new name added.

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])

const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const name = event.target.files[0].name
    setFiles(files=> [...files, name])
}
```